# dyld`__abort_with_payload: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SQLite.framework/SQLite Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have a successful builds of my project but I don't know what happened? right now it is showing this error, I have read a lot of similar questions from `stackoverflow` and other sources but nothing is helpful, here are the snaps of the error.

I am using only `SQLite.Swift` and `IQKeyboardManager`

I did clean, build, quiting xcode and relaunch it nothing helped

I have linked the frameworks. I have made them optionals & required as well and tried but still got errors

[image]

Here is the main error

[image]

The console:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried CMD-Shift-K?

Comment: yes dear I did clean, build, quiting xcode and relaunch it nothing helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Signing and Provisioning Profile in Xcode, make sure it's correct.

If it doesn't work, try a new certificate + new profile.